# Hide my menu using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap html menu:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
  <li class="dropdown menustatus">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
      <div class="busy-status"></div>
      <div class="online-status" style="display:none;"></div>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user" style="margin-top: 10px;">
      <li class="status">
        <a href="http://localhost:3000/status/online" data-remote="true" id="online-status" style="color:#4b3087;"><i class="fa fa-circle online"></i> Online</a>
      </li>
      <li class="status">
        <a href="http://localhost:3000/status/busy" data-remote="true" id="busy-status" style="color:#4b3087;"><i class="fa fa-circle busy"></i> Busy</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to hide the menu when the user click on any item, like this:

```
$("#online-status").click(function (){
  $(".busy-status").hide();
  $(".online-status").show();
  $("li.dropdown.menustatus.open").removeClass("open");
});

$("#busy-status").click(function (){
  $(".online-status").hide();
  $(".busy-status").show();
  $("li.dropdown.menustatus.open").removeClass("open");
});
```

But it does not work.

I also tried:

```
$(".dropdown.menustatus.open").removeClass("open");
```

or

```
$("dropdown.menustatus").removeClass("open");
```

or

```
$(".menustatus").removeClass("open");
```

or

```
$(".open").removeClass("open");
```

But I couldn't hide the menu.

What I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have a Fiddle or something? And showing your HTML / CSS would help too.

Comment: create a fiddle of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`#online-status` is an anchor.

Try:

```
$("#online-status").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   ....

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check how you did it with the other elements in the click events: You can in a similar way use `.hide()` and `.show()`, or even `.toggle()` if needed.

```
$(".menustatus").hide();
```

How specific the selector needs to be is up to you to decide / find out.

If you absolutely want to do it the "class way", my guess is that your ".open" class sets the visibility or display properties to visible/block or something similar to show the element, but your ".menustatus" does not seem to hide it. What I mean is: if you remove the .open class from the element, there is nothing that specifies whether it should be hidden or not. Try this:

```
.menustatus {
    display: none;
}

.menustatus.open {
    display: block; // Add !important if needed.
}
```

Change "block" to whatever you want, as long as it's not *none*.